# Build a DataFrame from lists of row index, column index, and value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I have three lists:

```
row = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
col = [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
val = ['', 'Heading', 'Prio', 'Black', 'USA', 'Inve', 'CAN', 'White', 'Busy', '', '', '', '', '', 'Req', '', '', '', '', '', 'Info', 'X', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'X', 'X']
```

Where `row` and `col` contain the indexes for each of the elements in `val`.

I want to build a DataFrame such that each element `val` is put in its appropriate spot, based off the elements of `row` and `col` (it should be noted that the indices of the elements in each list will always match up perfectly; the first element in `val` will always correspond to the row and column index given by the first elements in `row` and `col` and so forth).

Therefore the df created from the three lists above should look like:

```
|    |      |        Heading                   |
|---:|:----:|:----:|:----:|:----:|:----:|:----:|
|  0 | Prio | Black| USA  | Inve | CAN  | White|
|  1 | Busy |      |      |      |      |      |
|  2 | Req  |      |      |      |      |      |
|  3 | Info |   X  | N/A  | N/A  | X    | X    |
```

This is just an example, however, as I require the ability to do this for arbitrarily sized lists, with an arbitrary amount of row and column indices. How can I go about converting these lists into dfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to create a numpy array, then you can just fill it based on the row/col indices and convert that to a dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.full((max(row)+1, max(col)+1), '', object)
arr[row, col] = val
df = pd.DataFrame(arr[1:], columns=arr[0])
```

Output for your sample data:

```
        Heading
0  Prio   Black  USA  Inve  CAN  White
1  Busy
2   Req
3  Info       X  N/A   N/A    X      X
```